# Putting a custom object into a Hash

Tags: ruby, object, hash

I want to create an object defined by a class (for example, a dog) and then populate a hash with keys from a list and values being those objects. I'm trying to do it like so:

```
myHash = {}
class Dog
    attr_accessor :name, :weight
end

doglist = ['spike', 'spot']
doglist.each do |pupper|
    tempObj = Dog.new
    tempObj.name = pupper
    myHash.merge!(pupper: tempObj)
```

-at the end I'd want that hash to have the keys `spike` and `spot` having the names already stored. Whenever I try and use myHash['spike'].name I get:
 `undefined method "name" for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` as an output.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What would you like your final hash to look like?

Comment: If we were using the example I gave in the question my ideal resulting hash would end up like:
myHash = { 'spike' : <Dog Object with name spike>,
                   'spot' : <Dog Object with name spot>
                  }

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use an `initialize` method to set `name` and then use `map` and `to_h` to create your hash:

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :name, :weight

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

doglist = ['spike', 'spot']

myHash = doglist.map {|k| [k, Dog.new(k)]}.to_h
#=> {"spike" => #<Dog:0x00000001219ef8 @name="spike">,
#     "spot" => #<Dog:0x00000001219e58 @name="spot">  }

myHash['spike'].name #=> "spike"
```

---

As for fixing your method, use a `=>` instead of `:` otherwise the block parameter is interpreted as the symbol `:pupper` and that will be set as the key to your hash:

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :name, :weight
end

myHash = {}
doglist = ['spike', 'spot']

doglist.each do |pupper|
  tempObj = Dog.new
  tempObj.name = pupper
  myHash.merge!(pupper => tempObj)
end

myHash['spike'].name #=> "spike"
```

As a sidenote, use two spaces for indentation in Ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is: there is a drastic difference in `var: 42` and `var => 42` notations:

```
var = :foo
{var => 42}
#⇒ {:foo => 42}
```

while

```
{var: 42}
#⇒ {:var => 42}
```

In case of `key: value` notation, `key` is treated as a `Symbol` and is not expanded, while `key => value` uses the actual value of the `key` variable.

Also, instead of merging the single key-value pair, it’s more explicit to use the setter:

```
hash = {}
hash[var] = 42 # better than hash.merge!(var => 42)
#⇒ {:foo => 42}
```

That said, the following would work:

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :name, :weight
end

doglist = ['spike', 'spot']
doglist.each_with_object({}) do |pupper, acc|
  acc[pupper] = Dog.new.tap { |dog| dog.name = pupper }
  # or:
  # dog = Dog.new
  # dog.name = pupper
  # acc.merge!(pupper => dog)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The arguments to `merge!` should be a hash
`myHash.merge!({pupper => tempObj})`

Comment: In the `myHash.merge!(pupper: tempObj)` the argument is already a perfect hash.

Comment: When I run it with (pupper: tempObj), it uses "pupper" (the string) as the key instead of the value of pupper.  But when I run it with the arrow operator (=>) it uses the value of pupper as the key.  So I guess I should say use "=>" instead of ":".

Comment: Correct. And for `(pupper: tempObj)` it uses _not_ a `String`, but a `Symbol`.